# Separator_color use

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

Does anyone know how to edit this color to make black?

```
[47 / 255., 167 / 255., 212 / 255., 1.]
```

that is the code used as default, it makes a neon blue.

Comment: Show us the code you've tried, and tell us the error you got.

Answer (score 0):

If I wanted to create a black button that reads "My Button" in my Python file it would be the following:

```
my_btn = Button(text="My Button", background_color=(0,0,0,1))
```

You could then add this button to a layout and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

```
popup = Popup(title=self.ids["txt_faq_%s" % no].text,
              content=popup_content, separator_color=[255/255.,165/255.,0/255.,1.],
              size_hint=(None, None), size=(self.width/2, self.height/2))
```

Seperator_color is a ListProperty as stated in the documents: [kivy/docs/seperator_color](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.popup.html#kivy.uix.popup.Popup.separator_color)

Therefore, you need to convert the RGBA color code of black which is `(0,0,0,1)` into a list like that:

```
[0/255., 0/255., 0/255., 1.]
```

> (Red, Green, Blue, Alpha) => [Red/255., Green/255., Blue/255., Alpha]